How reduce the .aab size in flutter
I am create release.aab for upload on playstore (√ Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab (133.9MB)) , but this .aab size is big .how can i reduce this .aab size for publish on playstore.
I want to reduce the size . I need solution .

When upload aab file on play console .That auto reduce the size upto 60 - 70%.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
